# Shifted piecewise

Tags: python, sympy, piecewise

I want to have a series of piecewise functions with each being a shifted copy of the base function, but I do not know how to do that in sympy. Here is an example:

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import Piecewise
from sympy import And

x = Symbol('x')
s = Symbol('s')
f0 = Piecewise((1, And(x > 0, x < 1)), (0, True))
fs = f0(x - s)
```

However, the last line gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'Piecewise' object is not callable
```

How do I make a Piecewise callable and specify, that *fs* is a function of *x* and *s*?

Comment: Probably `f0.subs(x, x-s)`. I don't have sympy here, so I can't easily check.